# Auto Populate Account/Contact Names on new Case record

Tags: visual-workflow, service-cloud-console

Is there a better way to auto-populate the Account and Contact fields when creating a new case directly from the Account record page/related list?

I have a Screen Flow for Case creation, and I've tried adding GetRecords elements on the beginning of the Flow to retrieve the Account and Contact ID from the previous screen, in case there was one.

[image: Flow]

If yes, it would make the assignment and populate the Account and Contact fields on the Case object.
If not, it would continue with the flow.

It still hasn't worked, and I have not been able to find any useful, reliable answers online.

All I found out is that this seems to be a functionality that used to work in Classic, but doesn't in Lightning.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running the flow in [debug mode](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-testing-and-distribution/make-sure-your-flow-works) ?

Comment: I have, and apparently it's failing to find records on the GetRecords elements where I created a variable to store the data from the Account Id and Contact Id fields....

Comment: Creating a case from the contact should populate the values, I would think. Is that not the case (pun intended)?

Comment: I need it from account, but either way it doesn't work from contact either :(